# Using Schur-Weyl duality

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, symmetric-groups, symmetric-functions

I am trying to gain a better understanding of Schur-Weyl duality specifically applied to symmetric functions. My motivating example is trying to understand the Frobenius character of the multilinear component of the free Lie algebra (Theorem 8.1 in Reutenauer's book on the subject), but my general confusion is more than just that example. I feel comfortable with representation theory of finite groups and less so with representation theory of Lie groups.

[In](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/11/13/four-flavors-of-schur-weyl-duality/) [several](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/REU2016/REUPapers/Stevens.pdf) [sources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Weyl_duality), the statement of Schur-Weyl duality is framed as the $\operatorname{GL}(V)\times \mathfrak{S}_k$ isomorphism of the tensor algebra $V^{\otimes k}$ with the direct sum of tensor products $\mathbb{S}^\lambda(V) \otimes M^\lambda$ of Specht modules with Schur functors indexed by partitions of $k$ into at most $\dim(V)$-many parts. As I understand it, one can then determine the multiplicity of either a Schur functor (by looking at the dimension of the corresponding Specht module) or the multiplicity of a Specht module (by looking at the dimension of the corresponding Schur functor).

I also seem to understand that, as explained in the second appendix of Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics Vol. 2, the character value of $A \in \operatorname{GL}(V)$ for an irreducible rational $\operatorname{GL}(V)$ representation $\mathbb{S}^\lambda$ is given by evaluating the Schur polynomial on the eigenvalues of $A$.

Reutenauer's proof of theorem 8.1 (that two particular symmetric functions are equal) is as follows:

> This is the Schur-Weyl duality between the representations of the symmetric group and the general linear group (Weyl 1946, Theorem 7.6.F; Macdonald 1979, A7
> in Chapter 1).

My first confusion is that the references I find refer to Schur-Weyl duality as a statement about the tensor algebra, not any other algebra. The universal enveloping algebra of the free Lie algebra can be constructed as a quotient of the tensor algebra, so I'm willing to suspend some disbelief that the statement is still applicable here.

Even with that, I am having trouble connecting the dots here. Reutenauer sets up a $\operatorname{End}(V) \times \mathfrak{S}_k$-representation, and then looks at the action of a copy of $\mathfrak{S}_k$ living inside of $\operatorname{End}(V)$ and considers the Frobenius characteristic of the $\mathfrak{S}_k$-representation found by restricting the action of $\operatorname{End}(V)$. He then compares this to the multivariate generating function of dimensions of homogeneous polynomials of multidegree $\alpha$ which are stable under the $\mathfrak{S}_k \subseteq \operatorname{End}(V)$ action and asserts they are the same via the proof quoted above.

The character value of the restriction of a representation is just the character value of the original representation. The eigenvalues of any $A \in \mathfrak{S} \leq \operatorname{End}(V)$ should be all $1$. Then I think the character value of $A$ should be the number of semistandard Young tableaux of shape $\lambda$ with entries at most $\dim(V)$ (i.e. $s_\lambda(1,1,\ldots,1)$). But I am struggling to see why this proves Reutenauer's claim.

Any help or general information about the relationship between Schur-Weyl duality and symmetric functions you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**: I made some mistakes in my question including:

- The universal enveloping algebra is the tensor algebra, not a (nontrivial) quotient.
- Eigenvalues of permutation matrices are roots of unity, not 1.

Comment: The universal enveloping algebra of the free Lie algebra *is* the tensor algebra. I haven't looked at the rest of this but maybe that's already helpful. In any case, so that answering this question does not require having a copy of Reutenauer, it might be a good idea for you to include more of the text, e.g. the statement of the Theorem and a relevant section of the proof.

Comment: That is helpful in understanding why Schur-Weyl duality applies. Thank you! But I am still confused about how this turns into a statement about symmetric functions.

Comment: I find several parts of your question confusing (but I think this may because you are discussing a proof that you don't link to so I can't read in detail). For example, in the usual set-up of Schur-Weyl duality $V$ is an $n$-dimensional complex vector space acted on by $GL(V) = GL_n$, and we are looking at the action of $GL_n \times \mathfrak{S}_k$ on $V^{\otimes k}$ where the first factor acts diagonally and the second by permuting the copies of $V$. In general $n$ and $k$ are completely unrelated and so there is no natural inclusion $\mathfrak{S}_k \subseteq GL_n$ like you suggest.

Comment: Also, permutation matrices do not have all eigenvalues $1$. But again maybe I am misunderstanding some of your assertions because I can't look at the text you're trying to understand.

Comment: The problem is that whatever Reutenauer uses doesn't seem to be standard Schur-Weyl duality. I got confused by his symmetric group too -- his symmetric group $S_n$ acts diagonally through $\operatorname{GL}\left(V\right)$, not by permuting the tensor factors! The latter action wouldn't preserve the free Lie subalgebra (viewed as a subspace of the tensor algebra), so this is not surprising in hindsight, but it makes me wonder if Schur-Weyl duality is applicable at all.

Comment: Note that it may well be that the identity can be proved in a similar way to the Schur-Weyl duality character formula, viz., by computing the trace of some operator (probably a composition of the action of $\sigma$, the action of the diagonal matrix $\operatorname{diag}\left(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{\left|A\right|}\right)$, and perhaps the projection from $E_n$ onto $F \cap E_n$) in two different ways. But I don't find it obvious how. Fortunately, it seems that Theorem 8.1 is only used in the first proof of Theorem 8.3, while the second proof is self-contained (I hope; haven't checked).

Comment: @darijgrinberg: At the beginning of Chapter 8, before the statement of Theorem 8.1, Reutenauer in fact considers both of these actions of the symmetric group on the tensor product space (he calls them the "place permutation action" and the "variable permutation action").

Comment: Thanks Darij and Sam. I read through the proof on Wikipedia which Sam linked. I wonder if I am missing something. Wikipedia seems to prove the decomposition of the tensor power of $V$ into $\mathbf{GL}(V)$ irreducibles, but not into $\mathbf{GL}(V)\times S_d$ irreducibles. Am I missing something there?

Comment: @darijgrinberg I'm a little unsure about how to interpret applying the action of the diagonal matrix $\operatorname{diag}(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$. I get that the variables stand in for eigenvalues. In finite group representation theory we can fill in the character table. I see why no character table exists for $GL(V)$. Are we supposed to think of the symmetric polynomial output as a recipe for getting the characters of matrices? Does that mean that just restricting our attention to permutation matrices wont change the recipe so the character of the $S_n \leq GL(V)$ is the same polynomial?

Comment: I guess my last comment is a confusing way to ask: in finite group representation theory, the character values of the restriction of a subgroup are the original character values, you just forget some. In restricting from $GL(V)$ to $S_n$, does the same thing happen?

Comment: @SamHopkins, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1128851), I think your comment underrates the character: what you write down is the restriction to the diagonal torus of an honest, uniquely determined (subject to some restrictions) class function on $\operatorname{GL}_n$.  Of course it takes some work to evaluate that character on non-semisimple elements … but a permutation matrix *is* semisimple (all in characteristic $0$), so there's no harm thinking about evaluating a character by looking at its eigenvalues.  But maybe I misunderstood your point.

Comment: As pointed out in a now-deleted comment, restricting from $GL(V)$ to $S_n$ is an open problem! https://realopacblog.wordpress.com/2019/11/17/the-restriction-problem/

Comment: @TrevorK: Indeed, although your inquiries seem more related to a different open problem about symmetric functions, namely "Thrall's problem" (see https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~reiner/Talks/ThrallsProblem.pdf)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer is a response the the prompt

> Any help or general information about the relationship between Schur-Weyl duality and symmetric functions you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

If you have more questions (e.g. about the free Lie algebra), feel free to ask.

For convenience I will let $n = \dim(V)$.

Step 1: A bitrace formula.

As discussed, we have an action of $GL(V) \times S_k$ on $V^{\otimes k}$. We will compute the trace of an element $(M, g) \in GL(V) \otimes S_k$ on $V^{\otimes k}$. Conceptually we will think about $GL(V)$ and $S_k$ as separate (rather than combined into $GL(V) \otimes S_k$) which is why I use the term "bitrace" (it is the synthesis of two traces).

We compute the trace directly. The matrix $M$ has a Jordan decomposition $M = S + N$ ($S$ semisimple, $N$ nilpotent), and the action of $(M,g)$ on $V^{\otimes k}$ is the sum of the actions of $(S,g)$ and $(N,g)$; since $N$ is nilpotent, $(N,g)$ is not actually an element of $GL(V)\times S_k$, nevertheless the trace is well defined and equal to zero because it is nilpotent. I say all this only to justify restricting to diagonalisable matrices.

Now, let $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ be an eigenbasis of $M$, so that $Mv_i = x_i v_i$ for some complex numbers $x_i$ (i.e. $M = diag(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$).

This induces a basis $V_I = v_{i_1} \otimes \cdots \otimes v_{i_k}$ of $V^{\otimes k}$ indexed by words $I = (i_1, \ldots, i_k)$ (where $1 \leq i_j \leq n$). Conveniently, the action of $(M,g)$ on $V_I$ is easy to compute:
$$
(M,g) \cdot (v_{i_1} \otimes \cdots \otimes  v_{i_k}) = g \cdot (Mv_{i_1} \otimes \cdots \otimes Mv_{i_k}) = g \cdot (x_{i_1}v_{i_1} \otimes \cdots  \otimes x_{i_k}v_{i_k}) \\ = x_{i_1}x_{i_2}\cdots x_{i_k} (v_{g^{-1}(1)} \otimes \cdots \otimes v_{g^{-1}(n)})
$$
Side note: whether you apply $g^{-1}$ or $g$ to the indices depends on whether you view the symmetric group as having a left or right action, it's not really important.

This value of $(M,g) \cdot v_I$ is a scalar multiple of another basis element, which we might write $v_{g(I)}$ by using the induced action of $g \in S_k$ on tuples of length $k$. To compute the trace of $(M,g)$ we need to sum the "diagonal entries", i.e. the scalars corresponding to those $I$ with $v_I = v_{g(I)}$. This computation becomes
$$
\sum_{g(I) = I} x_{i_1} \cdots x_{i_k}.
$$
Now, suppose for example that $(2,5,6)$ is a cycle of $g \in S_k$. Then the condition $g(I) = I$ implies that the equality of indices $i_2 = i_5 = i_6$, but the actual value could be anything in $1, \ldots, n$. This condition also implies that $x_{i_2} = x_{i_5} = x_{i_6}$. This same reasoning extends to cycles of all sizes. The only nonzero "diagonal terms" to be summed are those where all indices acted on by a cycle of $g$ are the same. The actual index associated to each cycle is arbitrary, we we need to sum over those. If the cycles of $g$ have sizes $\mu_1, \ldots, \mu_l$, the trace becomes
$$
\sum_{j_1=1}^{n} \cdots \sum_{j_l=1}^{n} x_{j_1}^{\mu_1} \cdots x_{j_l}^{\mu_l} = (\sum_{j_1=1}^{n} x_{j_1}^{\mu_1}) \cdots (\sum_{j_l=1}^{n} x_{j_l}^{\mu_l}) = p_{\mu_1}(x) \cdots p_{\mu_l}(x) = p_\mu(x)
$$
where I am now using the standard notation for power-sum symmetric functions.

Conclusion: if the eigenvalues of $M$ are $x_i$ and $g$ has cycle type $\mu$, then the bitrace of $(M,g)$ acting on $V^{\otimes k}$ is $p_\mu(x)$.

Step 2: Frobenius characteristic and Cauchy identity.

The Frobenius characteristic, $ch$, is an isomorphism between the Grothendieck group of class functions on $S_k$ and symmetric functions of degree $k$ (here we work over $\mathbb{C}$). It is convenient to define $ch(f)$ for all functions on $S_k$ (not just class functions) by saying that if $g^*$ is the indicator function of $g \in S_k$, then $ch(g^*) = \frac{1}{k!} p_\mu(y)$, where $\mu$ is the cycle type of $g$, and I write $y$ for the symmetric function variables in order to distinguish them from the discussion in the previous step. So for example, if $C_{\mu}^*$ is the indicator function of the conjugacy class $C_\mu$ of elements of cycle type $\mu$, then $ch(C_{\mu}^*) = \frac{|C_\mu|}{k!} p_\mu(y) = \frac{1}{z_\mu}p_{\mu}(y)$, where $z_\mu$ has its usual meaning.

Now if we fix $M \in GL(V)$, then the bitrace of $(M,g)$ may be viewed as a (class) function on $S_k$, and so we may apply the Frobenius characteristic. If we write $cyc(g)$ for the cycle type of $g$, the result of this calculation is
$$
ch(tr(M,g)) = \sum_{g \in S_k} p_{cyc(g)}(x) \frac{1}{k!} p_{cyc(g)}(y) = \sum_{\mu \vdash k} \frac{1}{z_\mu} p_\mu (x) p_\mu(y).
$$
Now, the famous Cauchy identity implies that we have
$$
ch(tr(M,g)) = \sum_{\mu \vdash k} \frac{1}{z_\mu} p_\mu (x) p_\mu(y) = \sum_{\lambda \vdash k} s_\lambda(x) s_\lambda(y),
$$
where $s_\lambda$ is the Schur function indexed by $\lambda$.

This may be viewed as a symmetric-function-theoretic formulation of Schur-Weyl duality for the following reasons. Suppose we know that the Frobenius characteristic of the Specht module $S^\lambda$ is the Schur function $s_\lambda(y)$, and the character of the Schur functor $\mathbb{S}^\lambda(V)$ is the Schur function $s_\lambda(x)$ (the meaning of which is discussed in the comments to the original post). Then we have found that the bitrace (i.e. $GL(V) \times S_k$-character) of $V^{\otimes k}$ agrees with that of $\bigoplus_{\lambda \vdash k} \mathbb{S}^\lambda(V) \otimes S^\lambda$. By semisimplicity, these must be isomorphic.

For example, we can recover the multiplicity of the Specht module $S^\lambda$ in $V^{\otimes l}$ by computing $\dim(\mathbb{S}^\lambda(V))$, which is nothing but the trace of the identity of $GL(V)$. But the identity element of $GL(V)$ (viewed as a matrix) has $1$ as an eigenvalue repeated $n$ times, so the dimension is the evaluation $s_\lambda(1,\ldots,1)$ (where there are $n$ $1$-s), as you mention in your post.

Comment: This very directly points out the relationship between Schur-Weyl duality and symmetric functions. It also is nice that if you are dealing with symmetric polynomials (rather than functions) for the $s_\lambda(x)$, then it automatically enforces the limit on the length of the indexing partition.

Answer (score 2):

In your context, you want to think of the Schur-Weyl duality as a way to construct representations of $GL(V)$ out of representations of symmetric groups.

To give a precise answer along these lines that works well for your original motivation: let us denote by $Lie(n)$ the multilinear component in the free Lie algebra with $n$ generators. It has indeed an $S_n$-action coming from embedding $S_n$ into $GL_n$; you should think of this space as the space of abstract Lie operations that have $n$ arguments and are multilinear in them - forget about any free algebras for now. The point now (very well understood in the context of PI-algebras and of operads) is that out of the collection $\{Lie(n)\}_{n\ge1}$ you can construct free Lie algebras by the formula
$$
Lie(V)=\bigoplus_{n\ge1}Lie(n)\otimes_{S_n}V^{\otimes n},
 $$
where $S_n$ acts on $V^{\otimes n}$ by permutations of tensor factors.

It takes time to get used to the idea, but it has many powerful implications so it's totally worth it.